# How to download a zip on react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

on nodejs I'm sending the file as follows:

```
res.sendFile(fileName,{ root: path.join(__dirname, '../') });
```

on react i have been triying to dowload the file with axios with no success:

```
let dowloadGet = async (url, auth) => 
await axiosDownload.get(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth}` }, responseType: 'blob' });

  let response = await API.get(`${this.state.BE_route}/download_script_bytest/${this.props.test._id}`, this.props.idToken)

  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type:'application/zip'}));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.zip');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the file is created but it its corrupt, if i just visit the url the file gets downloaded correctly

Comment: You mean that `url` is working fine only when visiting it?

Comment: the get request is correct, when visiting it or using axios, however I am doing somenthing wrong when trying to convert the data to a zip file

Comment: @NilsonLagos Did you find anything, I have exact same prob